# Code block prefix text, like `visible`

Tags: bug, code-formatting

Recently I have repeatedly encountered a bug with the Markdown code block button. I’d usually select some block of code and click the button to make it indent by 4 characters and everything works.

Except that sometimes, a somewhat random string is added to the first line (the string always appears to be some parts of CSS).

Right now I can reproduce this only with the text `visible` being added in front of the line, but I did have different and also more broken text lines in the past. If I encounter any other later, I’ll add those as well. Anyway, here is an example where I just typed `Foo bar`, selected the line and clicked the button:

```
visibleFoo bar
```

Comment: When copying and pasting with Chrome, sometimes Chrome inserts non-breaking space characters at the start and indentation fails. Fix: manually backspace and reindent.

Comment: I use Firefox, and I *typed* the `Foo bar`. Also, the indentation works fine, there is just some new extra text…